# AZURE AD SSO does not authenticate my .NET application IIS

Tags: .net, iis, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I'm not very familiar with the IIS and Windows Server configurations. Here is the problem I am having: I created a test application that uses AZURE AD Single sign on. I registered the application to the Azure portal(with all localhost, live URI, and everything). When I test it on localhost, it is working. When I deploy it to our datacenters(that has SSL certs), it works. However, when I deploy the application into new IIS on AWS, although the sign in happens to AD, my application is not authenticated.

Below are the Request properties:

```
Request.IsSecureConnection//true
Url.Scheme //https
Request.IsAuthenticated //false
```

Anyone has an idea of why this is happening and how it could be fixed?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue:

On Azure Portal, you will need to register the application with URI www.xyz.com/myapp/

If you don't put the slash at the end of the URI, it does not authenticate you.